# CSS treats height differently than width?

Tags: css, html

On [this podcast](https://jeffandcaseyshow.com/jacs_0005_0010.html) it is stated that CSS widths are passed down to the children but the heights are passed up to the parents. The relevant portion starts at 11:43 and goes on for a few minutes.

While I unfortunately find it all too easy to believe that CSS does a weird thing like that, I would like to see an example page that demonstrates this.

Can someone make a page that clearly shows that the height is passed up rather than down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to down (*Outside* to *inside*). The outside height doesn't affect the inside.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.outside {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">Inside</div>
</div>
```

Down to up (*Inside* to *outside*). The inside height **does** affect the outside.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.inside {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">
    Inside
  </div>
</div>
```